What is the automorphism group of the projective line over a finite field?
I've run into some confusion with what is going on with the automorphism group of a finite projective line.
I think I understand what is happening in the case of the projective plane: For the projective plane over $\mathbb{F}_2$, we can look at all of the incedence-preserving maps from points to points and lines to lines on the Fano plane, which gives the correct result of $\text{PSL}_3(2)$. This generalizes to larger finite fields, and I think to higher dimensions as well.
But for the case of the projective line, I don't know what diagram/incedence structure I should be looking at. My first intuition would just be that the projective line would contain only the points of the field and $\infty$, and no lines, planes, etc. This would make the automorphism group be the full symmetric group on these points, as there is no structure to be preserved. Clearly I've misunderstood something here, as I know the algebraic groups $\text{PSL}_2(q)$ are not just the symmetric group in general.

You still want projective automorphisms to be induced from linear isomorphisms of $\Bbb F^2$.

@Ted: sure, but the question is what structure on the projective line itself this corresponds to. One could give a complicated scheme-theoretic answer but I think a simpler approach ought to be possible. I thought about this awhile ago and I think you might be able to do it with cross-ratios (that is, the structure is the data of which quadruples of points have any given cross-ratio) but I didn't check the details.

@QiaochuYuan Yes, sure, the cross ratio is the (unique) invariant of the projective group. Geometrically, I suppose we can think of projective automorphisms as projectivities from one line in the plane to another.
